# OpenGL, pitch forces yaw to be 0

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

So i have been learning opengl and 3d game programming, i started trying to make a camera class and implement movement and viewing with mouse.

Moving works flawlessly but looking around with mouse isn't working as it should.

Looking up without any problems only works when yaw is 0°, then i can look straight up. But when, yaw < 0 or yaw > 0, looking up wont be straight up but more like this ) or (  .

i also noticed that when yaw isn't 0 looking forces yaw to 0 while either looking down or up.

i dont understand why this is happening, why does pitch only work correctly when yaw is 0 and when it is not why does it forced yaw to be 0.

im following a tutorial nothing really seems wrong

processing mouse movement and updating

```
void Camera::processMouseMovement(GLfloat xOffset, GLfloat yOffset)
{
    GLboolean constrainPitch = true;

    xOffset *= this->mouseSensitivity;
    yOffset *= this->mouseSensitivity;

    this->yaw += xOffset;
    this->pitch += yOffset;

    if(constrainPitch)
    {
        if(this->pitch > 90.0f)
        {
            this->pitch = 90.0f;
        }

        if(this->pitch < -90.0f)
        {
            this->pitch = -90.0f;
        }
    }

    this->updateCameraVectors();
}
```

here's is my update function

```
void Camera::updateCameraVectors()
{
    Vector3 front;
    Matrix4 mat4;
    front.x = cos((DEG2RAD * this->yaw) * cos(DEG2RAD * this->pitch));
    front.y = sin(DEG2RAD * this->pitch);
    front.z = sin((DEG2RAD * this->yaw) * cos(DEG2RAD * this->pitch));

    this->front = mat4.normalize(front);
    this->right = mat4.normalize(mat4.cross(this->front, this->worldUp));
    this->up = mat4.normalize(mat4.cross(this->right, this->front));

    std::cout << "yaw: " << yaw << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pitch: " << pitch << std::endl;
}
```

in main.cpp

```
Camera camera(Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
GLfloat lastX = width / 2.0f;
GLfloat lastY = height / 2.0f;

GLboolean key[1024];
GLboolean firstMouse = true;

GLfloat deltaTime = 0.0f;
GLfloat lastFrame = 0.0f;
```

input with glfw, aslo in main.cpp

```
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallBack);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouseCallBack);

    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);
```

in main loop

```
    GLfloat currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
    deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
    lastFrame = currentFrame;

    glfwPollEvents();
    doMovement();


    proj = proj.perspective(camera.getZoom(), float(700 / 600), 1.0f, 1000.0f);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniProj, 1, GL_FALSE, proj.get());

    view = camera.getViewMatrix();
```

mouse callback function

```
void mouseCallBack(GLFWwindow *window, GLdouble xPos, GLdouble yPos)
{
    if(firstMouse)
    {
        lastX = xPos;
        lastY = yPos;
        firstMouse = false;
    }

    GLfloat xOffset = lastX - xPos;
    GLfloat yOffset = yPos - lastY;

    lastX = xPos;
    lastY = yPos;

    std::cout << "mouse position x: " << xPos << std::endl;
    std::cout << "mouse position y: " << yPos << std::endl;

    camera.processMouseMovement(xOffset, yOffset);
}
```

thank you :)

Comment: Do you have a single *specific* question? This seems to be very broad and kind of all over the place. Prefer to ask specific "why does this bit do this and not that" questions.

Comment: Which math library are you using? `mat4.normalize(front)` looks strange. What has a matrix to do with normalization?

Comment: ohh its a custom one, im gonna move the normal function from the matrix classes to my math class.

Comment: and i did try using glm for but the same problem occurs

Comment: mat4 is custom matrix, normalize is just within that class havent moved it to math class yet

Comment: it is used for the lookat matrix

Comment: What does `camera.getViewMatrix()` do?

Comment: it returns the current view matrix, because when looking it updates the view matrix parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `front` is your average-everyday forward vector, I would calculate it like so:

```
front.x = cos(DEG2RAD * this->yaw) * sin(DEG2RAD * this->pitch);
front.y = sin(DEG2RAD * this->yaw);
front.z = cos(DEG2RAD * this->yaw) * cos(DEG2RAD * this->pitch);
```

I'm not keen enough on my trigonometry to understand what your code is doing.

**UPDATE**: I stared at your code for a while... It looks like the outer set of parenthesis in your code is a mistake. The only other difference between my code and that is my use of `sin` when calculating forward.x, which would just swap an axis.

Comment: Someone just pointed out (and then deleted their comment) that my z-axis is positive when at zero pitch and yaw, which is backwards in OpenGL view matrix terms, where the forward z-axis is negative. That's true. I never noticed that with any of my camera instances.

Comment: Tysm, i changed it a little, didn't notice the mistake with the parenthesis and it actually works now. But changing cos to sin wasn't necessary.